# If the partition a Kafka producer try to send messages to went offline, can the producer try to send to a different partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

My Kafka cluster has 5 brokers and the replication factor is 3 for topics. At some time some partitions went offline but eventually they went back online. My questions are:

1. How many brokers were down does it indicate, given the fact that there were offline partitions? I think given the cluster setup above, I can afford to lose 2 brokers at the same time. However, if there were 2 brokers down, for some partitions they no longer have quorum; will these partitions go offline in this case?
2. If there are offline partitions, and a Kafka producer tries to send messages to them and fails, will the producer try a different partition that may be online? The messages have no key in them.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood your question completely right but I have the impression that you are mixing up partitions and replications. Or at least, your question cannot be looked at isolated on the producer. As soon as one broker is down some things will happen on the cluster.

Each TopicPartition has one Partition Leader and your clients (e.g. Producer and Consumer) are only communicating with this one leader, independen of the number of replications.

In the case where two out of five broker are not available, Kafka will move the partition leader as well as the replicas to a healthy broker. In that scenario you should therefore not get into trouble although it might take some time and retries for the new leader to be selected and the new replications to be created on the healthy broker. A leader selection can be made fast as you have set the replication factor to three, so even if two brokers go down, one broker should still have the complete data (assuming all partitions were in-sync). However, creating two new replicas could take some time dependent on the amount of data. For that scenario you need to look into the topic level configuration `min.insync.replicas` and the KafkaProducer confiruation `acks` (see below).

I think the following are the most important configurations for your KafkaProducer to handle such situation:

> **bootstrap.servers**: If you are anticipating regular connection problems with your brokers, you should ensure that you list all five of them. Although it is sufficient to only mention one address (as one broker will then communicate will all other brokers in the cluster) it is safe to have them all listed in case one or even two broker are not available.

> **acks**: This defaults to `1` and defines the number of acknowledgments the producer requires the partition leader to have received before considering a request as successful. Possible values are `0`, `1` and `all`.

> **retries**: This value defaults to `2147483647` and will cause the client to resend any record whose send fails with a potentially transient error until the time of `delivery.timeout.ms` is reached

> **delivery.timeout.ms**: An upper bound on the time to report success or failure after a call to send() returns. This limits the total time that a record will be delayed prior to sending, the time to await acknowledgement from the broker (if expected), and the time allowed for retriable send failures. The producer may report failure to send a record earlier than this config if either an unrecoverable error is encountered, the retries have been exhausted, or the record is added to a batch which reached an earlier delivery expiration deadline. The value of this config should be greater than or equal to the sum of request.timeout.ms and linger.ms.

You will find more details on the documentation on the [Producer configs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs).